# How do you debug Account Linking for Alexa skills using API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, alexa-skills-kit

I've been trying to link an Alexa skill and it has been outputting "Unable to link _ skill, please try again later".

I tried to follow this tutorial to build an API Gateway:

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/TxQN2C04S97C0J/How-to-Set-up-Amazon-API-Gateway-as-a-Proxy-to-Debug-Account-Linking.

But every time I try to create the stack, the build fails and this error is invoked in logs:

> CREATE_FAILEDAWS::ApiGateway::RestApiHTTPProxyAPIAPI: **s3:GetObject
>   Access Denied**

I'm not sure which role it is trying to access the s3 bucket with. But I've given all my roles/users full access to s3. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Does the user who you use to create the CloudFormation stack have `s3:GetObject` on the S3 bucket you are trying to access?

Comment: Yes, I do it as the user logged in, they are granted full s3 access

Comment: Did you have any bucket policy on the bucket?